# Payments in WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, payment

I am currently making a windows phone 8 silverlight app. 
In the app we would like to allow the user to pay through paypal or another way of paying. 
I also looked up the in app payments from the dev center, but did not manage to see a payment with variable values there.

Any help on what to use or examples about how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Update: according to the policy of the windows phone store you are not alowed to use paypal for example and can nly use Windows Phone in app payments.

Comment: I'd first read the Windows Phone Store agreement terms, before thinking about it. Unless your app is some kind of banking app, doing in-app purchases outside of the official in-app purchase SDK. Bypassing the in-app purchase SDK isn't allowed on most platforms. Google already banned apps asking for donations and unlocking of pro features with paypal & Co years ago. After all, in-app purchases/app purchases are the main source of income of smartphone OS developers

Comment: I have read that, and thats when i realized paypal wasn't ideal and started looking for alternatives. The next question is: does the windows phone in app purchase allow variable prices? I explained in the answer underneath that we have a catalog which changes daily so adding all items manually would be a time consuming and rather useless job. Or is there even an API to add all items when they are added to our store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example from visualstudiomagazine should work: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/in-app-purchasing-for-windows-phone-8.aspx

They explained it very good AND uses the legal way with the  Windows Phone SDK 8.0.

Comment: No problem. I wish you the best luck.

Comment: I just read the link you send, but am not sure if this also allows me to use variable prices. Since i just put them in on the windows phone dev center as static prices(there is no other option).
Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know you can update you prices in the center. Otherwise you delete the old item from the center and create a new one, but this need a update of your app.

Comment: Every payment will contain multiple items people want to buy. And there are multiple hundreds of items in the entire catalog. Can i then say, that item called PayEntireOrder now costs 50$ and next time 60$ ? Or is that impossible in the windows phone store?

Comment: I have to fit unfortunately, because I have not tried anything like that. However, I think that this can certainly be found somewhere in the center.

Comment: There is an option define market pricing, although i think that is only to set different prices in different countries with different valutas.

Comment: Alright. That's nice to know, thanks. Otherwise I hope that the link helped you to create purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Only those payment methods that support Windows store for IAP.