# Variable price windows phone in app purchase

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, payment

Hi I am currenly making a windows phone app which allows users to order multiple items. The only problem is the way of payment. 
Since windows phoen In app purchases are the only allowed way of paying by windows phone, I am not sure of how to make items with variable prices.

Would making an item, which costs 0.01€ or 0.01$ and just selling it 200 times at once to get the 2€/$ be OK or are there decent options, because this seems a very stupid way to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use third-party services for in-app purchases, for example PayPal even has an SDK https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/

Edit:

The latest "Windows and Windows Phone Store Policies" document (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx) doesn't prohibit you from using a different in-app financial service, see §10.8 and §10.8.2 specifically.

Comment: But is the paypal SDK allowed since i here asked: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790069/payments-in-wp8-app/29790286#29790286). And now know i can't use them, or is that wrong information?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the current policies.

Comment: Ill try the paypal SDK again, this seems the right solution to me

Answer (score 1):

This can only be understood through trial.
Change price, announcing a promotion. This is done easily in the store.
According to statistics, not always low price purchase leads to high income.
It eats the interesting data as 
[the purchase price and depends on your income.](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/12/22/windows-and-windows-phone-store-trends-december-2014-update/)

Comment: I know it should not be low to get high income, I asked some other questions on StackOverflow about the in app purchases, since I am looking for a way to make them variable since one user will only want one product and the other user will need a product of multiple hundreds of euros/dollars.

Comment: There are only different prices for the same product in different regions.

For users from one country price 1 $. For another 10 euros

Comment: So I suppose variable prices through the windows phone store are impossible?

Comment: Only the price is different for different regions.

You cannot vary the price to users from the same region.

Comment: Thanks for the information, seems like I will have to sort something out with PayPal then.